# Load special page if page doesn't exist (404)

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have a small function (below) that takes a parameter to determine what to load. Is there a way I can make it so that the .load() kind of has an "else" or a fallback if it ecounters a 404?

```
function start(page,last){
$("#area").load("pages/"+page+".inc.php");
loading();
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a function to be executed when the load completes.

Taken from the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Using your code it would look similar to this:

```
function start(page,last){
    $("#area").load("pages/"+page+".inc.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            // don't load as an error occured,...do something else...
        }
        else{
            loading();
        };
    });
}
```

You can check the linked documentation for more details on possible return values and errors. In fact the demo on the bottom of the documentation shows dealing with a 404.

`xhr.status` in the sample contains the error number `404` and the `xhr.statusText` is `Not Found`.

This would mean you can check for the specific number:

```
function start(page,last){
    $("#area").load("pages/"+page+".inc.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error" && xhr.status == ""404) {
            // a 404 occurred...
        }
        else{
            loading();
        };
    });
}
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/frKrX/)

Comment: I copied your version of the start() function and made an alert box if error however if I make 'page' blah nothing happens and according to the Inspector in Chrome all it has is the 404 for blah.inc.php   Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for the error however all the other links that call this function end up as an error. Here's what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/sjE96BLB

Comment: I think in my last edit I forgot to include the parameters. I added them now and also included a demo.

Answer (score 2):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has responseText and textStatus parameters that tell you when it succeeds so you can use that to check if it fails. A successful response will generate "success" or "notmodified" while an error generates "error".

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in the [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) you can define the status code like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert("page not found");
      //load the 404 page here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: should I put that snippet inside that function at the top? at the bottom? beginning of the script? In a doc(ready)? I put it after the original load but it didn't work.