# Jquery check if load success or fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to load content of external url into a div using JQUERY, I found that I should use the next command:

```
function loadMyContent(url){

    $("#result").load('registration.html');
}
```

Now I would like to check if the load was successful print alert message ("success") and if the action was fails from some reason alert ("fails").

1. how can I add the success and fails triggers to the function?
2. does the solution will cover also 404 errors?

Thanks alot
Shai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var page = $("#result");
$.get("registration.html").success(
function(response, status, jqXhr){
   alert("Success!");
   page.empty().append(response);
}).error(function (response, status, jqXhr){
   alert("Error.");
}).complete(function (response, status, jqXhr){
   alert("Complete!");
});
```

Comment: Not working, I getting error in the console: HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441020/jquery-ajax-exception-only-in-firefox-node-cannot-be-inserted-at-the-specified

Comment: refer this codes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924398/load-special-page-if-page-doesnt-exist-404?lq=1

Comment: On the link they said you should add the datatype as html to the get function and it should work, can you show me how to add it? cant get it to work

Comment: try with ` $("#result").empty().append(response);`

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the load function itself?

Answer (score 0):

He tried for get method but i saw you need use load if you wan't use load method try this (tested):

```
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
```